# Não mostra nome dos usuários no alert do Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Bom quero acessar o conteúdo de texto dentro da div e mostrar em um alert(), mas pra isso eu tenho uma lista de usuários selecionados do banco de dados, fiz um pequeno macete pra adicionar um contador em cada classe da div que contém o nome do usuário, veja o exemplo:

e assim sucessivamente.
Só que quuando eu coloco o alert(), ele exibe todos os usuários de uma vez dentro do alert, mesmo eu criando uma div para cada um. Alguém e dá um help.
meu Código:

```
$('.innerbox_contatos_search').click(function(){
  $('.info-part a').addClass('ativo');
  var i = 1;
  $(".ativo").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "ativo-"+i); 
    alert($('a.ativo-'+i).text());
  i++;
});
});
```

Comment: Podes colocar o teu HTML também?

Comment: O que exatamente você quer mostrar no alert?

Comment: Eu quero que ele mostre apenas a classe com o incremento de cada div, por exemplo quando eu clicar em David aparecer:
David e a classe do "David" vai ser:
<div class="ativo-1"></div>

Quando eu clicar em josé (que no caso é o segundo usuário), aparecer:
José e a classe do José vai ser:
<div class="ativo-2"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa do `i++` para realizar essa operação. Você não precisa de contador!

O `each` do jQuery usa o `this` dentro do callback como elemento atual dentro do contexto do loop.

Veja um exemplo modificado do seu código:

```
$('.innerbox_contatos_search').click(function(){
    $('.info-part').find('a').addClass('ativo');

    $(".ativo").each(function() { 
      // this é o elemento atual do loop
      alert($(this).text())

  });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcnj3utd/)

Comment: Wallace,
eu quero que ele mostre apenas a classe com o incremento de cada div, por exemplo quando eu clicar em David aparecer:
David e a classe do "David" vai ser:
<div class="ativo-1"></div>

Quando eu clicar em josé (que no caso é o segundo usuário), aparecer:
José e a classe do José vai ser:
<div class="ativo-2"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque você está colocando no alert todo o elemento. Você precisa o usar o *this* para acessar o conteúdo do elemento que foi clicado. Tente modificando seu código para:

```
$('.innerbox_contatos_search').click(function(){
  $('.info-part a').addClass('ativo');
  var i = 1;
  $(".ativo").each( function() {
    var textAlert = "ativo-"+i;
    $(this).attr("class", textAlert); 
    alert($(this).text() + " " + textAlert);
    i++;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo solução com base na solução dada pelo Wallace Maxters, acrescentando a aplicação da classe "ativo-i" nos elementos.

```
$('.innerbox_contatos_search').click(function(){
    $('.info-part').find('a').addClass('ativo');
    i=1;
    $(".ativo").each(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("ativo-"+i);
        console.log($('a.ativo-'+i).text());
        i++;
  });
});
```

Link funcionando no JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moneisa123/qxjh1ycw/4/